# How to change return type based on a function input which is a class name?

Tags: kotlin

I have multiple data classes and each class has a corresponding class containing more info. I want to write a function in which I should be able to pass an identifier (table name corresponding to the data class). Based on this identifier, object of the corresponding class should be made, the value changed and this object should be returned as output of the function. I have written a simplified version of it on playground but I am unable to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
class someClass(
)

class objectForSomeClass(
    var value: String
)

class someOtherClass(
)

class objectForSomeOtherClass(
    var value: String
)

class doSomething() {
    companion object {
        val classMap = mapOf(
            "someClass" to objectForSomeClass::class,
            "someOtherClass" to objectForSomeOtherClass::class,        
        )
    }

    // Create a map of class name to a new object based on the class name input
    fun dummyFun(className: String, valueInput: String): Map<String, kotlin.Any> {
        var returnObject = mutableListOf<Pair<String, kotlin.Any>>()
        when(className) {
            "SOME_CLASS" -> {
                returnObject = mutableListOf<Pair<String, justDoIt.classMap["someClass"]()>>()
            }
            "SOME_OTHER_CLASS" -> {
                returnObject = Map<String, justDoIt.classMap["someOtherClass"]()>
            }
        }
        returnObject[className].value = valueInput
        return returnObject
    }
}


fun main() {
   var obj = doSomething()
   var t = obj.dummyFun("SOME_CLASS", "Value to be inserted")
   // do something with t
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing more about your classes (the ones in your code are not data classes – a *data class* in Kotlin is a specific type of class) I still think a lot could be simplified down to maybe even this:

```
fun createObject(className: String, value: String): Any? {
  return when (className) {
    "SomeClass"      -> ObjectForSomeClass(value)
    "SomeOtherClass" -> ObjectForSomeOtherClass(value)
    // ...
    else             -> null
  }
}
```

Additionally:

The *classMap* is not necessary, you can hard-code the cases in the *when* clause as in my example. There is also no need for reflection, which you would need to create instances from *SomeType*::class.

With getting rid of *classMap* you also do not need the companion object holding it anymore, and then you are left with one function for creating instances of your classes, and this function does not have to be in a class. You might put it into a singleton class called object in Kotlin (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-expressions)

Data classes in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html

You could maybe also replace each *class someClass* & *class objectForSomeClass* pair with a *class someClass* with a *companion object*.